# Make glob directory variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, glob

I'm trying to write a Python script that searches a folder for all files with the `.txt` extension. In the manuals, I have only seen it hardcoded into `glob.glob("hardcoded path")`.

How do I make the directory that glob searches for patterns a variable? Specifically: A user input.

This is what I tried:

```
import glob

input_directory = input("Please specify input folder: ") 
txt_files = glob.glob(input_directory+"*.txt")
print(txt_files)
```

Despite giving the right directory with the `.txt` files, the script prints an empty list `[ ]`.

Comment: are you on windows, mac or linux?

Comment: and you might just be missing a backslash (or forward slash) in your input search pattern

Comment: Can you show the output of `print(input_directory+"*.txt")`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not sure whether a path contains a separator symbol at the end (usually `'/'` or `'\'`), you can concatenate using [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join). This is a much more portable method than appending your local OS's path separator manually, and much shorter than writing a conditional to determine if you need to every time:

```
import glob
import os

input_directory = input('Please specify input folder: ') 
txt_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(input_directory, '*.txt'))
print(txt_files)
```

Answer (score 2):

For Python 3.4+, you can use [`pathlib.Path.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) for this:

```
import pathlib

input_directory = pathlib.Path(input('Please specify input folder: '))
if not input_directory.is_dir():
    # Input is invalid.  Bail or ask for a new input.
for file in input_directory.glob('*.txt'):
    # Do something with file.
```

There is a [time of check to time of use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) race between the `is_dir()` and the glob, which unfortunately cannot be easily avoided because `glob()` just returns an empty iterator in that case.  On Windows, it may not even be possible to avoid because you cannot open directories to get a file descriptor.  This is probably fine in most cases, but could be a problem if your application has [a different set of privileges from the end user](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confused_deputy_problem) or from other applications with write access to the parent directory.  This problem also applies to any solution using `glob.glob()`, which has the same behavior.

Finally, `Path.glob()` returns an iterator, and not a list.  So you need to loop over it as shown, or pass it to `list()` to materialize it.